# How to add preview button in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I have a set of textareas which are behaving as  ckeditors.
But I want to include the preview icon in the toolbar.

below is my javascript function

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
    $(this).ckeditor();
});
```

Can somebody help Me on this?

Answer (score 2):

[Preview is a plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/preview). Make sure your copy of CKEditor includes it (you didn't say a word about which CKEditor you use) and update your [config.plugins](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-plugins) so it's loaded.

This is [where to set configurations](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration) (also [with jQuery adapter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery)).